How do I create a RAM drive in Windows 10 using PowerShell?
I've read this article, OS Hub - Creating In-Memory RAM Drive on Windows Server, on creating a RAM Drive for Windows Server using PowerShell (which is perfect when handling sensitive data temporarily that requires a file path).
But since Windows 10 can't act as an iSCSI Provider with native tools, that won't work.
# Install the features
Install-WindowsFeature -Name FS-FileServer
Install-WindowsFeature -Name FS-iSCSITarget-Server

Start-Service MSiSCSI

# Open local firewall if necessary
Set-NetFirewallRule -Name MsiScsi-in-TCP -Enabled True
Set-NetFirewallRule -Name MsiScsi-out-TCP -Enabled True

# Allow iSCSI LoopBack
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\iSCSI Target' -Name AllowLoopBack -Value 1

# Setup an iSCSI disk
New-IscsiVirtualDisk -Path 'ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx' -Size 100MB
New-IscsiServerTarget -TargetName targetRAMDisk -InitiatorIds @("IPAddress:<YOUR-IP-HERE>")
Add-IscsiVirtualDiskTargetMapping -TargetName targetRAMDisk -DevicePath "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx"
Get-IscsiTarget | Connect-IscsiTarget #! Non is found before they are discovered :/

# Format the drive
Get-Disk | where PartitionStyle -eq 'raw' |
  Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru |
    New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize |
      Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'RAMdisk' -Confirm:$false

According to the article, your remove the disk on a Windows Server using
Remove-IscsiVirtualDiskTargetMapping -TargetName targetRAMDisk -DevicePath "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx"
Remove-IscsiServerTarget -TargetName targetRAMDisk
Remove-IscsiVirtualDisk -Path "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx"

So, any takes on other methods of creating RAM Drives using PowerShell that will work with Windows 10/11?
Maybe there is even a C# implementation available of Windows 2000 Ramdisk.sys (KB257405) available somewhere that could be adopted for PowerShell?

You might have better luck with something like ImDisk http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk

To add to the lmDisk comment: remember that powershell is still a shell, so once the tool is installed you can call it directly. You don't need separate cmdlets for it.

Can you expand on "Windows 10 can't act as an iSCSI Provider with native tools"?

@MathiasR.Jessen, the feature FS-iSCSITarget-Server isn’t available on Windows 10. It’s a server feature.

@JoelCoehoorn, well. I’ve built Winform applications in the past using PowerShell (ver 2.0 even). So it’s a h*ll of a Shell
